# Conditional formatting for multiple blank cells and running total in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to track voting attendance for meetings and I'm having varying degrees of successes.

Problem Scenario:

Column H, I, and J contain either a 1 or a blank and represent if they attended one of the last 3 meetings. 
For all rows if ALL 3 Columns (H, I, AND J) are BLANK or "", mark that entire ROW RED
Then I need to SUM the number of rows that are marked RED and subtract that from voting members.

I've tried leveraging Conditional Formatting tool > Custom Formula with not much success.  Below are some of the things I tried and failed even on the first part of my scenario.

```
=IF(SUM(H4:J4)>0,false,true)

=ISBLANK(H4:J4)

=IF(ISBLANK(H4:J4),false,true)

=ARRAYFORMULA(OR(ISBLANK(H4:J4))) = FALSE
```

None of these quite worked as hoped and even copying to each row and pasting conditional formatting also messed up the formula further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For formatting:**  Use the Conditional Formatting using the `COUNTBLANK(range)` formula.

1. Go to Conditional Formatting
2. Select the range you want formatted (in your case `H1:J50` assuming 50 rows)
3. Select `Custom Format is`
4. Add the expression `=countblank($H1:$J1)=3`
5. Select red from the color palette
6. Press `Done`

Then your blank rows will now be highlighted red.

**To Count the Blank rows:**

1. Choose an used column.
2. Enter the expression `=if(countblank($H1:$J1)=3,1,0)` in Row1 and auto fill as many rows as needed.
3. Total at bottom and use this value for you subtraction.

There may be easier ways but `=if(countblank($H1:$J1)=3,1,0)` will put a `1` in the row if H1:J1 are all blank.

Comment: Check if above works for you. If not let me know and I will post a test sheet to demonstrate. I tested it and it worked on my test sheet.

Comment: Thank you!  This seemed to get me part way there.
The formula to count the number of blank rows didn't seem to work.
Also, it seems if I add a new column to the "left of H" so that I can keep an entire history but still track the last 3 months.... the conditional formatting automatically updates.  While I agree that is usually very helpful... is there a way to prevent  that?

Comment: Simple mod to get the counter working:
=if(COUNTBLANK($H2:J2)=3,1,0)

Comment: I found a way to do it, but it super sucks.  Can't copy and paste it.  Have to manually do it for each line because it makes you put the row values as a string...

=if(COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("$H2:J2"))=3,1,0)

Same for the conditional formatting.

Any suggestions on something better?

Comment: oops `=if(countblank($H1:$J1),1,0)` was a typo on my part because my test sheet had `=if(COUNTBLANK($H1:J1)=3,1,0)` (else it would not have worked) . I'm glad you found it! I have updated the reply in case anyone else comes across the solution.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "add a new column to the "left of H" so that I can keep an entire history ....". If you explain that a bit more - maybe send me a link to a test sheet and I will take a look.

Comment: Also if formulas are not enough you have the option to make a Javascript function that say, executes after every edit of any cell, and this can be made to do anything you like.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rs-RtcBkOvQIrD0egra21zgyqC8znk4YNT4Ir56KXcU/edit?usp=sharing)
If I want to keep history... I keep adding a new column to the left of I with a new date.  Using INDIRECT I was able to get this working because INDIRECT uses a string.  But I have to manually update each line and I can't easily copy to another line or Drag Copy... editing the lines would be difficult, but it DOES work right now with the existing INDIRECT command.